# Thread wait in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety, android-asynctask

i have one problem with handling the thread in android ,in my class i have to create one thread which create some UI after that thread finish i will get some value ,here i want to wait my Main Process until the thread complete it process but when i put wait() or notify in Main process  thread does not show the  UI  in my application

this is sample code

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         downloadThread = new MyThread(this);
            downloadThread.start();

            synchronized(this){  
                try {
                    this.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

 String test=Recognition.gettemp();
    public class MyThread extends Thread {
        private Recognition recognition;

        public MyThread(Recognition recognition) {
            this.recognition = recognition;
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
    synchronized(this)

            {                

                        handler.post(new MyRunnable());

                }

                notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
    static public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
                settemp(template);
            }

        }
    }

    public static String gettemp() {
        return template;
    }
    public static void settemp(String template) {
        Recognition.template = template;
    }

}
```

here i will not use AsynTask because i have some other issue that is reason i choose Thread even now the problem is Thread wait do any give the suggestion for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the logic below :-

```
new Thread(new Runnable() 
{
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        //do the code here such as sending request to server
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                //do here the code which interact with UI
            }
        });
    }
}).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

**-** Use `java.util.CountDownLatch` , here you can let some process complete before kick-off some other code.

**-** `countDown()` and `await()` will be of use to you.......

**See this example of CountDownLatch:**

http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/CountDownLatch.shtml

Comment: The main problem is that the poster is locking the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect to happen if you freeze the main UI thread?

You should be using an ASyncTask to show your gui in the onPreExecute method, do the task in doInBackground  then display the result in the onPostExecute method.

As a plus you can update the progress using onProgressUpdate too.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an solution just a advice on how should you structure you activity/app.

You should never block the main thread by calling `wait()` its a bad user experience and not advised. It would also case a Android Not Responding (ANR) popup.

You can have you thread updating the UI from the background and let the UI to be responsive. Load the static part of your UI in `onCreate()` and then fire up the background thread to lazy load rest of the component.